# Qt could not find the platform plugin cocoa

Tags: c++, qt

I'm experimenting a little bit with Qt. I have successfully written a small app which works fine on my Windows 8.1 Laptop. Now I installed XCode and Qt and copied the project folder to my MacBook. The application compiles fine on my Mac but when I wan't to run it via Qt Creator I'm getting the following errors:

```
[qt.qpa.plugin] Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstall application may fix this problem.
```

I have read that the tool `macdeployqt` is needed when I want to deploy the app to other PCs. But shouldn't my application run without `macdeployqt` when I execute it directly with the Qt Creator?

I'm using MacOS X 10.14 with Qt 5.11.3. Xcode 10 and the MacOSX SDK 10.13 is installed and setted up correctly (at least it compiles with this SDK and without any error).

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted the same question a few days ago on the official Qt forum, because I haven't got a response here on Stackoverflow: https://forum.qt.io/topic/98816/qt-could-not-find-the-platform-plugin-cocoa

The problem seems to be that I've installed Qt on /Library/Qt *(outside of the user directory)*. After reinstalling Qt to /Users/ABC/Qt and a complete rebuild of my project everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 46):

If you are on Mac, go to the Terminal and paste the following:

```sh
pip3 install opencv-python-headless
```

The Qt platform plugin requires this library to be installed.

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to test some of the experimental features such as "cv2.aruco", which are not found in opencv-python-headless. Also trying to run on Visual Studio Code

Comment: This solution worked like a charm on MacOS Mojave (10.14.6) running Python 3.7.7. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks! @b.sodhi

Comment: I wonder why you need to use _Python_ to add the library?...

Comment: As it is a cross platform library, I found python method easy than using any other language like C++, perl etc...

Answer (score 15):

Try setting QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH to the plugin directory of where you installed qt.

E.g. if QT is installed in /Users/ABC/qt, then
    export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Users/ABC/qt/plugins
likely fixes your problem (did it for me on my brew installed qt).

Comment: @HayoBaan Thanks, man, it works as expected for Homebrew'ed QT and gnuplot. In my case (Homebrew in user home directory) it was `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=~/homebrew/opt/qt/plugins` that solved the problem.

Comment: Hm. That works for sure, at least once you figure out the path for _your_ Mac, but... this is not something that can be demanded from end-users installing the app! Isn't there a way for the app to automatically locate the missing plugin and load it?

Comment: Sorry about my last comment, I was confusing 'local runs' with 'deployment' (using `macdeployqt`). Anyway, is there a way to automate this step, even for local runs?

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn I have absolutely no experience with deploying QT-applications, but if you deploy your app, isn't QT bundled with it? If so, you'll know the path so you can automatically set this in the applications run script, right?

Comment: +1 However I compiled Qt from src, and it wanted `plugins/platforms` instead. (Apple Silicon, Ventura, Qt6)